# XSLT for-each, where position() = 1

Tags: xslt, xpath, foreach, xslt-1.0

If I have an XPath to a NodeSet - it is my understanding that the following XSLT will iterate over each node that matches the provided XPath.  And the "value-of" function, matching on "." should return the data from each matching node.

`<xsl:for-each select="//some/X-Path/Here/*">

  <xsl:value-of select="." />

</xsl:for-each">`

What if I have an xpath to a single element though?  Suddenly doing a "for-each" over that single node seems silly.  But I can't find a comparable "feature" in XSLT that accomplishes the same behavior - but where the input is just a single element, rathern than a collection.

`<xsl:match select="//some/X-Path/Here[1]">

  <xsl:value-of select="." />

</xsl:match">`

Or something to this effect.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried `<xsl:value-of select="//some/X-Path/Here[1]"/>`?

Comment: Yes - and that puts exactly what I want to work with directly into the output.  I want to be able to actually DO something with those nodes.  In other words, I don't just want the value of that node, I want to make the "Current" context that node, so that I can then do a for-each (for example) over some values inside of that node.  Does that make sense?

Comment: There's no such feature because there's no need for it - a for-each over a singleton node set might look a bit odd at first glance but it does precisely what you require, there's no need to complicate the language with an additional construct that does exactly the same as for-each apart from complaining if you give it more than one node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you basically answered your question yourself. Iterating over a node set of size one *may* look a little strange but there are other ways to do it. One is creating a match template as you suggested and having it called through `<apply-templates>`. The other way is to insert the value directly as @halfbit suggested. IMHO it is very difficult to say what is the best method. It definitely depends on the context.

However, maybe two more thoughts in favor of `<for-each>` compared to using `<value-of>`.

- The former only execute if the expression actually *exists* whereas the latter always executes. This is, of course, not not bad for the `<value-of>` part since it should be emtpty but it may be unhandy if it is surrounded by wrappers which might screw up your output. So in other words a

  ```
  ...
  <xsl:for-each select="//some/X-Path/Here/*">
    output something here
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    output something here
  </xsl:for-each"> 
  ...
  ```

  has an implicit if-condition for the block, which on the other hand the construct

  ```
  ...
  output something here
  <xsl:value-of select="//some/X-Path/Here/*" />
  output something here
  ...
  ```

  does not. So, you would have to surround it by an `<if>` then:

  ```
  ...
  <xsl:if test="//some/X-Path/Here/*">
    output something here
    <xsl:value-of select="//some/X-Path/Here/*" />
    output something here
  <xsl:if>
  ...
  ```
- The other thing is that the `<for-each>` tag changes the context node which may be handy if you want to access more than element down the path of your XPath. So, for example,

  ```
  ...
  <xsl:for-each select="//some/X-Path/Here/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="@attr1" />
    <xsl:value-of select="@attr2" />
    <xsl:value-of select="@attr3" />
    ...
    <xsl:value-of select="@attrN" />
  </xsl:for-each"> 
  ...
  ```

  is simply shorter (and *may* be easier to read) than

  ```
  ...
  <xsl:if test="//some/X-Path/Here/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="//some/X-Path/Here/*/@attr1" />
    <xsl:value-of select="//some/X-Path/Here/*/@attr2" />
    <xsl:value-of select="//some/X-Path/Here/*/@attr3" />
    ...
    <xsl:value-of select="//some/X-Path/Here/*/@attrN" />
  <xsl:if>
  ...
  ```

  especially if you have a lengthy XPath expression.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful and complete response Marcus!  You've nailed it.  I'm trying to get the "context switching" aspect of the for-each, but syntactically more inline with a single selection - like:  <xsl:select-node match="x/y/z"> (context switched in here) </xsl:select-node> or something.

Comment: Yes, I've often thought it would be nice to have something more readable than xsl:for-each for this, but adding a 100% redundant construct just for readability seems wrong.